# Strange characters in two arduinos trying to connect with nRF24L01+

Tags: arduino

am trying to connect 2 nRF24L01+ modules that just arrived in my inbox with 2 arduinos.

I am using the RF24 library with client in one and server on the other, pingpair, scanners. On ALL of them I am getting strange characters in Serial terminal display:

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, I am unable to proceed any further.

Comment: I can't believe you solved that so easy. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the kind of garbage one gets when the serial settings are wrong (wrong baud rate, parity, stop bits, etc...). Do you have any reason to believe this is a problem with the nRF24L01+, and not the serial communications you are using to read the output?